# Setting first color in basemap colorbar to gray not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am using the foll. code to plot colorbar in the map below

```
        import palettable
        cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.PuRd_9.mpl_colormap
        lcmap = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
        lcmap[0] = (.5, .5, .5, 1.0)  # force the first color entry to be grey
        cmap = cmap.from_list('custom cmap', lcmap, cmap.N)  # create the new map
```

However, the resulting map does not have the first color as gray. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your cmap definition, `lcmap` is 256 entries long, and setting only the 0th entry to a new color is barely visible in the colorbar or in a dataset that has few of the lowest values. I exaggerated it by (1) setting the new color to green, for maximum contrast, and (2) setting the 32 lowest entries of lcmap to the new color, and it's fine. In the basemap example file [plotsst.py](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/figures/plotsst.py) the result is:

[image]

from inserting this code to replace the line that defines `im1`:

```
import palettable
cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.PuRd_9.mpl_colormap
lcmap = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
for i in range(32):
    lcmap[i] = (0, .5, 0, 1.0)
cmap_green = cmap.from_list('0th entry green', lcmap, cmap.N)

im1 = m.pcolormesh(lons,lats,sst,shading='flat',cmap=cmap_green,latlon=True)
```

`palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.PuRd_9` has nine values, as expected, but turning it into a `mpl_colormap` smooths it out to 256.

Incorporating @Pablo Reyes' answer, the inserted code is

```
import palettable
cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.PuRd_9.mpl_colormap
lcmap = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
lcmap[0] = (0, .5, 0, 1.0)
cmap_green = cmap.from_list('0th entry green', lcmap, 9)

im1 = m.pcolormesh(lons,lats,sst,shading='flat',cmap=cmap_green,latlon=True)
```

and the result is

[image]

There you go!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `cmap.N` use the number of segments you have, 9:

```
import palettable
cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.PuRd_9.mpl_colormap
lcmap = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
lcmap[0] = (.5, .5, .5, 1.0)  # force the first color entry to be grey
cmap = cmap.from_list('custom cmap', lcmap, 9)  # create the new map
```